# Tag merge request: [address-bar] and [addressbar]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

On StackOverflow, there are 46 questions tagged [addressbar](/questions/tagged/addressbar) and 23 tagged [address-bar](/questions/tagged/address-bar). They describe the same thing as far as I can tell. I think they should be merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the questions tagged with [addressbar](/questions/tagged/addressbar) have been merged over into [address-bar](/questions/tagged/address-bar) and I've suggested an edit to the tag wiki to transfer that over, since it didn't have one.